# How to fix Visual Studio 2015 Installation for specific failed components?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

Just went through an install of Visual Studio 2015.  Some packages failed to install. Here are the packages

**Android SDK Setup (API Level 19 and 20)**
The following package(s) were not downloaded: addon-google_apis_x86-google extra-android-support. Please check your internet connection and try again.

**Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) 14.0.23026**
Another version of this product is already installed.

**Microsoft Visual Studio Connected Services**
Package failed.

**Azure AD Authentication Connected Services**
Package failed.

**Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Connected Services**
Package failed.

**Microsoft Azure Storage Connected Services**
Package failed.

**Microsoft VisualStudio.Office365**
Package failed.

What are my options here? Do I really need these services?  The most important is the android SDKs as I am wanting to do Xamarin development. Is it possible to install the specific SDKs (or any of these packages) separately?

Note: This was actually a repair install. All the Connected Services and Office365 had failed on the original install. So, I doubt another repair will take care of the problem.

Thanks for any suggestions you may offer.

Comment: The error message about Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86), you can go to Control Panel-Programs and Features and search this program, that you will find a higher version than 14.0.23026. If so, you can just ignore it, since a higher version already installed and you can use this component.

Comment: Hi xgp, does your issue is solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the error message about the android SDK packages, you can have a try with the following methods:

1. Open Android SDK Manager and click Tools-Options… and check the option “Force https://... Sources to be fetched using http://...” and try to download those android SDK packages again.
2. Have a look at this similar issue: [Visual Studio 2015 setup issue with Android SDK – hack it!](https://askguanyu.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/visual-studio-2015-setup-issue-with-android-sdk-hack-it/), if you found the same root cause: all google repositories don’t have this package anymore on your side, you can try to create your own repository contains this missing package and let Visual Studio setup “think” he download the package and unzip it successfully.

If your network is behind a proxy, you can also have a look at this blog: [Visual Studio 2015 install failures (Android SDK Setup) behind a Proxy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/peterhauge/2016/09/22/visual-studio-2015-install-failures-android-sdk-setup-behind-a-proxy/) and follow the steps as below to fix it:

•   BEFORE installing Visual Studio, create a file at this location:  %USERPROFILE%.android\androidtool.cfg

•   In the androidtool.cfg file that you just created, place those content from the blog.  Make sure to update “http.proxyPort” and “http.proxyHost” in the file!

•   Install Visual Studio normally

If the uninstall still failed, you use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.